# Open Excel Documents with Google Sheets from Laravel App

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-sheets, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel and I'm facing a challenge trying to open excel sheets from my application. Is there a way in which i can open uploaded excel sheets with google sheets in the browser without having to download.

Any assistance?

Comment: First you'd need to upload them into Google Sheets, I believe. What exact challenge are you having, btw? Your description of the issue is vague - please read [ask].

Comment: Apologies for my short explanation @ADyson, i have a case where users share documents via the system, like pdf and excel. For Pdf the browser has the support of reading in the browser without downloading it to a local computer. In the case of Excel sheets, the user has to download it first before opening it. In this case i would like to stream with google sheets on click

Comment: Ok. So again, you first need to put the spreadsheet into Google Sheets. Sheets can't open documents which aren't stored in its system, as far as I know.

Comment: Regards @ADyson, I found that solution, i just thought maybe there could be other way

Comment: `i have a case where users share documents via the system` Can you provide more details about this "system"?

Comment: @lamblichus, This is an internal Laravel app for communication. In the app there is an ability to share documents and excel sheets are among the common ones. I was just looking for a way a user can open an excel sheet with google sheets without having to download in to his/her computer just like how we open images and PDF

Comment: Have you considered [uploading the file to Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads) via Drive API? You can upload it directly to Sheets, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66548228/upload-a-excel-file-with-google-drive-api), for example. I don't know the detail of you app workflow though, so I don't know whether this would be feasible in your case.